# Android USB Debugging on Samsung Infuse 4G

Tags: android, testing, usb, device, adb

I am trying to test an Android application through the Eclipse plugin on a real device. It is a Samsung Infuse 4G. I believe I have followed all steps on the Android page for testing on devices.

First of all, I cannot figure out what the Android OS version is because it does not show up in the settings. I can see that the firmware version is 2.2.1, so I assume I am running that version of Android OS as well.

Next, when I connect the device to my computer (running Vista, 64 bit), I get prompted with three options: Kies (firmware update), Media player, and Mass storage. When I look on the Internet, I see that I am supposed to select "Charge only", but this does not appear in the options with which I am prompted. I have already set USB Debugging to true through Settings > Applications > Development.

Third, I have installed the correct driver from the Samsung site based on my model number (SGH-I997), yet when I do adb devices from my platform-tools directory (I have tried adb kill-server and adb start-server), I still do not get my device listed.

I am not very advanced in terms of working with Android and have been banging my head against the wall on how to solve this problem, so any and all help guiding me through this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: On your mobile, Application-> Development ->check USB Debugging in checked

Comment: I have made sure that this is checked.

Comment: Sorry, I had seen the grayed out checkbox, so I assumed this meant that it was checked by default. Works perfectly now that I actually checked the box and see a green checkmark. Thanks and sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this PC Suite ...**Samsung Kies** http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP this would help you to get the exact driver for the device  and don't forget to check USB Debugging option in settings.

Comment: I installed this software, but it still says "Please connect a device" in the upper left even after I troubleshooted my connection. The Kies software even said "Connection error troubleshooting process complete".

Comment: Sorry, I had seen the grayed out checkbox, so I assumed this meant that it was checked by default. Works perfectly now that I actually checked the box and see a green checkmark. Thanks and sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to mark "Allow Mock Locations "in Development Options in Applications settings of your phone.

Also try enabling ,use as mass storage after connecting your device.

You can check if your device is detected in device tab of DDMS in Eclipse.

Even trying all such things ,it does not work try connecting your device 2 or 3 times ,restarting eclipse and enabling USB Debugging and mock locations again

Comment: This is checked on the device. I did try doing that, but it is still not being recognized in the DDMS tabs. It has not shown up any of the times I have restarted.

Comment: Sorry, I had seen the grayed out checkbox, so I assumed this meant that it was checked by default. Works perfectly now that I actually checked the box and see a green checkmark. Thanks and sorry for the trouble!