# Unable to debug application over USB; works with emulator

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, usb, adb

Android Studio on Windows - Following successful Gradle sync and build, I am unable to launch my application on my (rooted) Android Galaxy S3 and debug via USB. I have [USB Debugging enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20343210/3063884) on my device.

I *am* able to:

- provision and debug via the debug interface on the emulator
- see my USB device in the Android DDMS window:

  [image: DDMS Window - Device Connected]
- manually provision via adb, then connect via the debugger, using the same commands that come out of the debug window in Android Studio:

---

```
Cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools"
adb -d shell 
su
pm uninstall com.company.myapplication
ls -all /data/app | grep myapplication
pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.company.myapplication"
am start -n "com.company.myapplication/com.company.myapplication.MapsActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

---

- Following manual provisioning (see above), I can attach to the running process on my device, and debug (including hitting breakpoints):

  [image: Android Choose Process]
- Select my device from the "Choose Device" window when attempting to initiate USB debugging:

  [image: Choose Device - physical device present]

  ... following which I get the following output (and no activity on the Android device UI):

---

```
Waiting for device. 
Target device: samsung-sgh_t999-6XXXXXX2
Uploading file
    local path: D:\Data\XXXXXX\Sandpit\XXXXXX\MyApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.company.myapplication
Installing com.company.myapplication
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.company.myapplication"`

Launching application: com.company.myapplication/com.company.myapplication.MapsActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "com.company.myapplication/com.company.myapplication.MapsActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process: com.company.myapplication
```

---

In the case above, after checking files using the adb shell, I have noticed that the `pm install` command works -- i.e. there's an updated file (based on timestamp) in location `/data/local/tmp/com.company.myapplication`. However, the `am start` doesn't work, as the .apk file under

I have tried:-

- [Restarting the computer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14570176/3063884)
- Restarting the Android device
- Reinstalling Android Studio
- Run app (rather than Debug app): same result, no app installation on Android device
- Creating a new test application to see whether it's a problem with Gradle or Manifest configuration problems in my original application.
- Cleaning the project
- Connecting as both a `Media device (MTP)`, and also as `Camera (PTP)`
- [Enabling mock locations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13677813/3063884) (`Settings -> Developer options -> Allow mock locations`)
- [Adding `android:debuggable="true"` to the Android Manifest XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753939/not-able-to-debug-app-in-android-studio) (`<appRoot>\MyApplication\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`), despite IDE suggestion to the contrary:
  [image: android:debuggable attribute]
- Ensuring ADB Integration is enabled:

  [image: ADB Integration Setting]
- Toggling the ADB connection on the phone (`Settings -> Developer Options -> USB Debugging check/uncheck/recheck, reconnect`)
- Updating to the [latest Samsung drivers for the S3](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SGH-T999ZAATMB) - downloaded, refreshed in Windows Device Manager:

[image: Samsung ADB Device in Device Manager]

- Restarting the ADB Server, including as root, then re-connecting (and subsequently re-attempting debugging from Android Studio over USB):

---

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools>adb wait-for-device

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
6XXXXXX2        device


C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools>adb root

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools>adb wait-for-device

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
6XXXXXX2        device


C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools>
```

---

Versions:-

- I had Android Studio v0.8.2, but as part of my testing efforts have since downgraded to 0.8.1, which also doesn't work (same problem).
- Cell phone is SGH-T999, Android version 4.1.2
- OS is Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

  **What have I omitted? What else should I try?**

Comment: Have you checked if usb debugging is enabled on your Phone?

Comment: Yes, see included step "Toggling the ADB connection on the phone (Settings -> Developer Options -> USB Debugging check/uncheck/recheck, reconnect)"

Comment: Sorry your question was so detailed i was to lazy to actually read all of it. (;

Comment: I think I've done everything that I can to get it working! I've since hooked up an AM335x board, and it debugs fine off the bat. I think it's possibly something with my S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to provide closure... I ended up dropping this device, and it wasn't worth repairing the screen, so this device no longer exists. My new device - also an S3 - works after being rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe installing the Universal ADB Driver will help. ([Download](http://dl.cdn.chip.de/downloads/19253538/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi?1406915275-1406922775-89cad2-B-ca65ed8928627477034d8572cc5ae355))

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. The download link is out of date, but I did manage to find 'UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi' here (I'm assuming it's the same one):   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shabbypenguin/One-Click-Nexus/master/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi

Comment: I'm assuming that the Universal ADB Driver is just an update of the Google Nexus driver with the hardware IDs from various devices included in it (à la http://stackoverflow.com/a/15609366/3063884)...